# Group , Sort List of Tuple with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have list of Tuple like this :

```
List<Tuple<int,int, string>> list;
```

And with filled Values :

```
1,200,"somelabelForHeaderA"
2,200,"sometextA"
3,200,"sometextA"
4,222,"somelabelForHeaderB"
5,222,"sometextB"
6,222,"sometextB"
7,300,"somelabelForHeaderC"
8,300,"sometextC"
9,401,"somelabelForHeaderD"
10,401,"sometextD"
11,401,"sometextD"
12,401,"sometextD"
```

now what i want to do is sort and group like this :

```
1,200,"somelabelForHeaderA"  <== ***Must Be Inserted in Column 1 Row 1*** 
2,200,"sometextA sometextA"  <== ***Must Be Inserted in Column 2 Row 1***
3,222,"somelabelForHeaderB"  <== ***Must Be Inserted in Column 1 Row 2***
4,222,"sometextB sometextB"  <== ***Must Be Inserted in Column 2 Row 2***
5,300,"somelabelForHeaderC"  <== ***Must Be Inserted in Column 1 Row 3***
6,300,"sometextC"            <== ***Must Be Inserted in Column 2 Row 3***
7,401,"somelabelForHeaderD"  <== ***Must Be Inserted in Column 1 Row 4***
8,401,"sometextD sometextD sometextD" <== ***Insert in Column 2 Row 4***
```

and then insert each "somelabelForHeader" and "sometext" in one row.

this is as far as i go :

```
     var grouped = list.GroupBy(t => t.Item2, t => t.Item3)
.Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, string.Join("\n", g)));

 foreach (var groups in grouped)
                {
     using (SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(Connection_String))
                 {
                  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                       cmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
                       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                       cmd.CommandText = query;
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", groups.Item2);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", "???");
                            try
                            {
                                sqlconnection.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (SqlException ex)
                            {

                            }

                        }
                    }
```

with above  code i can group and concat all text but how can sort and extract first row before insert ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var query = Items
    .GroupBy(i => i.Item2, i => i.Item3)
    .SelectMany(g => new[]
    {
        new { b = g.Key, c = g.First() },
        new { b = g.Key, c = String.Join(" ", g.Skip(1)) },
    })
    .Select((x, i) => Tuple.Create(i + 1, x.b, x.c));
```

The key is to create separate rows for the header (the first item of the group) and the text parts (the rest).  Then from there, you can generate the new counters to create your final tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var grouped = list.GroupBy(t => t.Item2)
.Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key,g.Max(i=>i.Item3),g.Min(i=>i.Item3),g.Count()));
```